# Poedit - what does "end-of-line within string" mean?

Tags: cakephp, translation, poedit

When I load a catalogue file, I get following errormessage:

**12:39:07: /var/folders/l_/10kq10v961s1hxrvldh2x85c0000gn/T/poedittGhuHb/1input.po:7859: end-of-line within string**

12:39:07: /Applications/Poedit.app/Contents/MacOS/msgmerge: found 1 fatal error

12:39:07: Katalogeinträge sind möglicherweise ungültig.

12:39:07: Aktualisierung des Kataloges fehlgeschlagen. Klicken Sie für weitere Informationen auf 'Details >>'.

Does somebody know what this means?

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I forgot the closing `"` on a string I added for translation in the `*.po` file.

Answer (score -1):

It means that in some file somewhere, you have a newline within a quoted string -- as the error says. Because you don't provide any other information, it's impossible to say much more.

P.S. There are [better places where to discuss Poedit issues](http://www.poedit.net/support.php) (be sure to include [all relevant information](http://www.poedit.net/trac/wiki/HowtoReportBugs)).